# Populate the value in datetimepicker from the database

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.NET

I want to display the date in datetimepicker from the database.

Code.

```
cmd= new sqlcommand("select date from table1", con)
dr = cmd.executereader
while dr.read()
datetimepicker1.value.add(dr("Date"))
end while 
dr.close
```

But it showing error as specified cast is not valid

How to get a value?

Need vb.net code Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime.Add doesn't do what you think it does. It adds a TimeSpan (not a date) to an existing date. In your case you have a date, not a timespan, and want to set it on a datimepicker, not add a period of time to it.

You should do this instead:

```
datetimepicker1.Value = dr("Date")
```

If dr("Date") is of type Object, you'll need to explicitly convert it to a Date object like this:

```
datetimepicker1.Value = CDate(dr("Date"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the value to DateTime,  the problem is that dr("Date") is a string and in your code your making a string value equal to a DateTime and that's the error your seeing.  Try putting

datetimepicker1.value.add(DirectCast(dr("Date"), DateTime))

This should cast the string value to a DateTime value.  One thing you might want to add to your code is a check to make sure the value of dr("Date") is actually a date and not some other value type.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Another way to get the date value assigned would be to use datetimepicker1.value = DirectCast(dr("Date"), DateTime))

Comment: Erm - that's not quite right dr("Date") isn't a string is it? It might default to a string but its an object value if not explicitly typed.

Comment: Murph you are correct, it is an object.  My bad, was pulling from memory on that one, thanks for correcting me.